# Set Textbox = Today() When Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox

I have a webform where I have two textboxes and the user is supposed to input a date.  Sometimes the user will not input a date, and I do not want to make the input required, so to combat this, i want to set the NULL textbox value to today's date.  This is the syntax that I am working with, but my compiler is giving me an error of (2 different errors)

> Use of unassigned local variable 'ads'
>   Use of unassigned local variable 'ade'

What do I need to do alter so that my code will 

1) If the textbox is not null, accept the date input
2) if the textbox is null, force the textbox to show todays date?

```
DateTime ads;
DateTime ade;
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
string s_today = today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

string a = txtads.Text;
if (a != "")
{
  ads = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
  txtads.Text = ads.ToShortDateString();
}
else { txtads.Text = s_today;}
string b = txtade.Text;
if (b != "")
{
  ade = Convert.ToDateTime(b);
  txtade.Text = ade.ToShortDateString();
}
else { txtade.Text = s_today; }
Runthisstoredparemterizedprocedure(database, ads, ade);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pre-fill the textbox with today's date, and leter the user override it if he wants. That way, you do not have a problem and you can for extra good measure do a:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(myTextBox.Text))
  myTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

You probably need to fiddle a little with syntax, but that should get your question answered.